# How to re-spawn particles randomly in Away3D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, particle-system, away3d

I'm attempting to create a particle effect using [Sparticle](http://www.effecthub.com/t/sparticle) and Away3d. The effect is a little burst of bubbles that float up to the top of the screen when items are clicked.

I have the effect loaded and working and it looks good, but unfortunately the effect always spawns the bubbles with the same random velocities each time. The velocities seem to be set when the animation first runs and then never changes.

How do I restart the animation with new velocities each time?

I've tried calling `stop` and `start` on the animator, and `resetTime` but I suspect it's just moving the time back to 0 and that's why the animation isn't actually restarting properly.

i.e.

```
particleGroup.animator.stop();
particleGroup.animator.start();
```

The `reset` method doesn't do anything because it expects an animation name, and the animation name set in the sparticle editor doesn't seem to be available.